# tf: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past

Tags: transforms, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've written the following method for returning the homogeneous transformation matrix between two tf links:

```
Eigen::Matrix4f getTransformation(std::string parentName, std::string childName){
  parentName.insert(0,"/");
  childName.insert(0,"/");
  tf::StampedTransform transform;
  tf::TransformListener listener;
  ros::Time t = ros::Time::now();
  try{
    listener.waitForTransform(parentName, childName, t, ros::Duration(4.0));
    listener.lookupTransform(parentName, childName, t, transform);
  }
  catch (tf::TransformException ex){
    ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
  }
  tf::Matrix3x3 rot = transform.getBasis();
  tf::Vector3 trans = transform.getOrigin();
  Eigen::Matrix4f tranformation = Eigen::MatrixXf::Identity(4,4);
  Eigen::Matrix3f upleft3x3;
  upleft3x3 << rot[0][0], rot[0][1], rot[0][2],
               rot[1][0], rot[1][1], rot[1][2],
               rot[2][0], rot[2][1], rot[2][2];
  tranformation.block<3,3>(0,0) = upleft3x3;
  tranformation.col(3) = Eigen::Vector4f(trans[0],trans[1],trans[2],1);
  return transformation;
}
```

When I try to use this method, I get the following error:

```
Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1406560524.442721448 but the earliest data is at time 1406560524.444821575, when looking up transform from frame [wrist_3] to frame [base_link]
```

I tried the solution suggested by Martin Günther on [this page](http://answers.ros.org/question/38222/tf-extrapolation-exception-using-rostime0/), but that just resulted in an infinite while loop.

Adding a `ros::Duration(1)` to the requested time worked, but obviously that isn't ideal. Any other solutions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188023/tf:-lookup-would-require-extrapolation-into-the-past/) by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-28**:
When does this happen? Once at the start or all the time?

**Comment by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) on 2014-07-28**:
I get the error whenever the function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should ask for the last known transform with `Time(0)` instead of `Time::now()`

```
  ros::Time t = ros::Time(0);
```

---

Originally posted by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) with karma: 454 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) on 2014-07-28**:
That worked. Thanks!

**Comment by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on 2014-07-28**:
Check out this tuto http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20%28C%2B%2B%29 for details about tf and times